# Centralize input label when error class exists

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use horizontal form and custom errors:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <form name="ctrl.myForm" ng-submit="ctrl.save()">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 text-center">
      <color-picker selected="ctrl.selectedColor"></color-picker>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-error">

      <label for="logName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Log Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label ng-show="ctrl.logNameHasError" class="control-label" for="logName">
          <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Input with error
        </label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.logName" class="form-control" id="logName"
               placeholder="Enter a new log name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.isDailyDigestEmail"> Daily Digest Email
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.isNewErrorEmail"> New Error Email
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Open [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/buvudanape/edit?html,output) please and you will see that `Log Name` field has wrong alignment. How to center it?
Make output window in JSBIN as 768px minimum to see what I mean.

Comment: Can't you put your error after that `input` ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: Actually, no, because it's by design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can add css when `.has-error` class is exists:

```
.form-group.has-error .col-sm-3.control-label {
    padding-top: 34px;
}
```